# Is there a way to produce a FittedModel object as the solution to a regularized regression?

Tags: fitting

I can get the Ridge or Tikhonov regression solution to `Y = \[Beta].X` easily enough as

```
\[Beta] = 
 Inverse[Transpose[X].X + \[Lambda] IdentityMatrix[
      Dimensions[X][[2]]]].Transpose[X].Y
```

for a given regularization parameter `\[Lambda]`.

But I want to use LinearFitModel (or otherwise) to create a FittedModel object so I have access to all it's availible statistics and properties. I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to do this or if it's even possible. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: It's been a long time without any comments or answers on this question.  Does anyone have any input?  I was unable to add much unfortunately myself, but would appreciate if anyone has any useful input.  I believe this is an important method that Mathematica should have readily available as a part of its linear regression functionality.